# Using C variable inside Lua alongside nested functions

Tags: c, variables, lua, nested

This is a sort of followup to my previous question about nested registered C functions found here:
[Trying to call a function in Lua with nested tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366287/trying-to-call-a-function-in-lua-with-nested-tables/13367675#13367675)

The previous question gave me the answer to adding a nested function like this:

```
dog.beagle.fetch()
```

I also would like to have variables at that level like:

```
dog.beagle.name
dog.beagle.microchipID
```

I want this string and number to be allocated in C and accessible by Lua.  So, in C code, the variables might be defined as:

```
int microchipIDNumber;
char dogname[500];
```

The C variables need to be updated by assignments in Lua and its value needs to be retrieved by Lua when it is on the right of the equal sign.  I have tried the __index and __newindex metamethod concept but everything I try seems to break down when I have 2 dots in the Lua path to the variable.  I know I am probably making it more complicated with the 2 dots, but it makes the organization much easier to read in the Lua code.  I also need to get an event for the assignment because I need to spin up some hardware when the microchipIDNumber value changes.  I assume I can do this through the __newindex while I am setting the value.

Any ideas on how you would code the metatables and methods to accomplish the nesting?  Could it be because my previous function declarations are confusing Lua?

Comment: There is literally no difference between setting variable values and functions in lua - named functions are just anonymous function that have been assigned to variables. I'm not sure, but it sounds like your problem is that you're setting the metatable with __newindex on dog rather than dog.beagle

Answer (score 1):

The colon operator (`:`) in Lua is used only for functions. Consider the following example:

```
meta = {}
meta["__index"] = function(n,m) print(n) print(m) return m end
object = {}
setmetatable(object,meta)
print(object.foo)
```

The index function will simply print the two arguments it is passed and return the second one (which we will also print, because just doing `object.foo` is a syntax error). The output is going to be `table: 0x153e6d0 foo foo` with new lines. So `__index` gets the object in which we're looking up the variable and it's name. Now, if we replace `object.foo` with `object:foo` we  get this:

```
input:5: function arguments expected near ')'
```

This is the because `:` in `object:foo` is syntactic sugar for `object.foo(object)`, so Lua expects that you will provide arguments for a function call. If we did provide arguments (`object:foo("bar")`) we get this:

```
table: 0x222b3b0
foo
input:5: attempt to call method 'foo' (a string value)
```

So our `__index` function still gets called, but it is not passed the argument - Lua simply attemps to call the return value. So don't use `:` for members.

With that out of the way, let's look at how you can sync variables between Lua and C. This is actually quite involved and there are different ways to do it. One solution would be to use a combination of `__index` and `__newindex`. If you have a `beagle` structure in C, I'd recommend making these C functions and pushing them into the metatable of a Lua table as C-closures with a pointer to your C struct as an upvalue. Look at [this](http://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/lua_pushcclosure) for some info on `lua_pushcclosure` and [this](http://www.lua.org/pil/6.1.html) on closures in Lua in general.

If you don't have a single structure you can reference, it gets a lot more complicated, since you'll have to somehow store pairs `variableName-variableLocation` on the C side and know what type each is. You could maintain such a list in the actual Lua table, so `dog.beagle` would be a map of variable name to one or two something's. There a couple of options for this 'something'. First - one light user data (ie - a C pointer), but then you'll have the issue of figuring out what that is pointing to, so that you know what Lua type to push in for `__index` and what to pop out for `__newindex` . The other option is to push two functions/closures. You can make a C function for each type you'll have to handle (number, string, table, etc) and push the appropriate one for each variable, or make a uber-closure that takes a parameter what type it's being given and then just vary the up-values you push it with. In this case the `__index` and `__newindex` functions will simply lookup the appropriate function for a given variable name and call it, so it would be probably easiest to implement it in Lua.

In the case of two functions your `dog.beagle` might look something like this (**not actual Lua syntax**):

```
dog.beagle = {
  __metatable = {
    __index = function(table,key)
      local getFunc = rawget(table,key).get
      return getFunc(table,key)
    end

    __newindex = function(table,key,value)
      local setFunc = rawget(table,key).set
      setFunc(table,key,value)
    end
  }
  "color" = {
    "set" = *C function for setting color or closure with an upvalue to tell it's given a color*,
    "get" = *C function for getting color or closure with an upvalue to tell it to return a color*
  }
}
```

**Notes about the above:** 1.Don't set an object's `__metatable` field directly - it's used to hide the real metatable. Use setmetatable(object,metatable). 2. Notice the usage of `rawget`. We need it because otherwise trying to get a field of the object from within `__index` would be an infinite recursion. 3. You'll have to do a bit more error checking in the event `rawget(table,key)` returns `nil`, or if what it returns does not have `get`/`set` members.